Aerial Picture Ground Footprint Calculation
I've been working on an application that, given an aerial picture taken by a drone and the coordinates of an object of interest, tries to determine whether the object is located within the ground footprint of the picture.
In order to achieve this, I'm trying to figure out what the most accurate way to compute the ground footprint of an aerial picture is.
My understanding is that the image is nadir, the footprint can be calculated as follows:
footprint_width = sensor_width * altitude / focal_length
footprint_height = sensor_height * altitude / focal_length
Is this correct?
If the picture wasn't taken perpendicularly, how do pitch, yaw, and roll factor into this calculation?

The first question is not strictly mathematical in nature, and would be better asked in a forum with experts in cameras or optics (the physics forum would satisfy the latter). The second question is mathematical, but is stated in terms of pitch and roll (yaw is immaterial), which are engineering/orienteering terms not used much in mathematical discussions. These two issues severely limit your audience in this forum.

In general terms, if the camera is not facing directly perpendicular to the footprint, then the footprint will not be rectangular, but rather a more general convex quadrilateral. If roll is $0$, but there is some pitch, it will be an isosceles trapezoid, with top larger than the bottom. Adding roll as well distorts it so there no parallel sides, nor are any sidelengths going to be equal, in general. So your simple "width & height" descriiption will no longer be applicable.
